# Given a energy band diagram, can you always calculate potential, electric field, and charge distribution?

Tags: semiconductors, physics, solid-state-devices

Given a band diagram, where do you start to get the electric field and charge distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always calculate these.

The energy band diagram is proportional to electric potential. It is energy of electrons which can be converted to voltage by dividing by the charge of an electron. The electric field is the derivative of voltage with respect to position and the charge is proportional to the derivative of electric field.